# Как удалить из Map по дате рождения

Tags: java, map

Надо удалить из словаря всех людей, родившихся летом.
попытался через contains() не принимает

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMMMM d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    HashMap<String, Date> map = new HashMap<String, Date> ();
    map.put ("Stallone", df.parse ("JUNE 1 1980"));

    //напишите тут ваш код
    map.put ("Stallone1", df.parse ("JULY 1 1981"));
    map.put ("Stallone2", df.parse ("AUGUST 1 1982"));
    map.put ("Stallone3", df.parse ("SEPTEMBER 1 1983"));
    map.put ("Stallone4", df.parse ("OCTOBER 1 1984"));
    map.put ("Stallone5", df.parse ("NOVEMBER 1 1985"));
    map.put ("Stallone6", df.parse ("AUGUST 1 1986"));
    map.put ("Stallone7", df.parse ("JUNE 1 1987"));
    map.put ("Stallone8", df.parse ("JUNE 1 1988"));
    map.put ("Stallone9", df.parse ("JUNE 1 1989"));

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, Date> pair : map.entrySet ()) {
        String key = pair.getKey ();
        Date value = pair.getValue ();
    }

}
```

Comment: Используйте пакет `java.time`. Там нормально можно с датами работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, вы можете пройтись по словарю, проверить его значение (дата) и сохранить нужные ключи.

После, имея нужные ключи удалить их из словаря.

Пример:

```
...

List<String> removeKeys = new ArrayList<>();

for (HashMap.Entry<String, Date> pair : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = pair.getKey();
    Date value = pair.getValue();

    // Код для получения месяца
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(value);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    // Включает в себя июнь, июль и август
    if (month >= 5 && month <= 7) {
        removeKeys.add(key);
    }
}

// Удаление из словаря
map.keySet().removeAll(removeKeys);

System.out.println(map);
// {Stallone4=Mon Oct 01 00:00:00 YEKT 1984, Stallone5=Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 YEKT 1985, Stallone3=Thu Sep 01 00:00:00 YEKST 1983}
```

Еще можно решить это без дополнительных коллекций и переборов, используя итератор:

```
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    Date value = map.get(key);

    // Код для получения месяца
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(value);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    // Включает в себя июнь, июль и август
    if (month >= 5 && month <= 7) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня включены вот такие импорты какие ище нужны

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Calendar;

Comment: Забыли List, ArrayList (они будут в `import java.util.`)? А так, тыкаете на не импортированный объект и тыкаете Ctrl + Space и IDE импортирует

Comment: для удаления есть готовый метод `removeAll(Collection)`

Comment: `map.entrySet().removeAll()`

Comment: @user9545468, пожалуйста :), а вариант с `removeKeys` не сработал?

Comment: должен сработать тоже

Comment: Собственно, внутри готового метода `removeIf()` точно такой же итератор, один в один. Только предикат отдельно задается.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(pair -> {
    int monthValue = pair.getValue().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate().getMonthValue();
    return monthValue >= 6 && monthValue <= 8;
});
```

Но я бы все таки изначально не использовал устаревшие классы `Date` или `Calendar`

Comment: java8 streams это тема :)